# python pandas | triple conditional statments

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, conditional-statements

| volume | price | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 3 | 2021-09-29 04:00:00-04:00 |
| 900 | 2 | 2021-09-29 04:30:00-04:00 |
| 900 | 5 | 2021-09-29 05:30:00-04:00 |
| 500 | 9 | 2021-09-29 06:00:00-04:00 |
| 900 | 22 | 2021-09-29 06:30:00-04:00 |
| 900 | 1 | 2021-09-29 07:00:00-04:00 |

What I am trying to do : "between 2021-09-29 04:15:00-04:00 and  2021-09-29 06:35:00-04:00, return the price with the max volume. If there is more than one row/record with max volume, then return the lowest price out of them (expected output is 2)"

I have the below but I don know how to nest the between statement in there

```
df[df.volume == df.volume.max()].price.min()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `df.sort_values` method to sort on multiple columns. Here is an example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "volume": [100, 900, 900, 500, 900, 900],
        "price": [3, 2, 5, 9, 22, 1],
        "datetime": pd.to_datetime(
            [
                "2021-09-29 04:00:00-04:00",
                "2021-09-29 04:30:00-04:00",
                "2021-09-29 05:30:00-04:00",
                "2021-09-29 06:00:00-04:00",
                "2021-09-29 06:30:00-04:00",
                "2021-09-29 07:00:00-04:00",
            ]
        ),
    }
)
# select the date range
df_in_date = df.loc[
    (df["datetime"] >= "2021-09-29 04:15:00-04:00")
    & (df["datetime"] <= "2021-09-29 06:35:00-04:00")
]
# sort by the volume (descending) then the price (ascending)
# the first row contains the lowest price for the maximum volume
lowest_price = df_in_date.sort_values(
    ["volume", "price"], ascending=(False, True), ignore_index=True
).loc[0, "price"]
print(lowest_price)
```